# Should I open a separate MySQL connection for each statement executed?

Tags: mysql

Is it a good idea to open a single MySQL connection (from C#) and then use that same connection to perform multiple SQL statements? Or should I open and close a separate MySQL connection for each statement I need to execute?

Is something like this (the pseudo-code below) possible, or should I avoid the pattern of running multiple SQL statements using the same connection?

```
MYSQL.OPEN()
FOR(INT I =0 ; I < CODE.COUNT ; I ++)
{
ALL ITEMS I WANT ENTER BY ONCE TIME OPEN CONNECTION ( is it possible) or wrong idea ?
}
MYSQL.CLOSE()
```

Comment: i want open once time connection for database and enter all rows and then close connection . or i need open and close conection after every row enter into databse ?

Comment: You should tag your question with the appropriate language tag. (C#, VB.NET, php ???) Otherwise we can't give an understandable example

Comment: are you trying to insert queries by any server-side language or in mysql console?

Comment: +1 @user1551503: This was a good question to ask, about the suitability of a pattern. I edited your question, and elaborated a bit on it, to provide a little more information. If anything I added was not what you intended, if this wasn't the question you were asking, then you can edit the question, and remove anything that isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't churn connections.

Open the connection to the MySQL database, do all the work you need to do, then close the connection.

Opening and closing a connection for each SQL statement is a LOT of heavy lifting for the database server to do. (It looks simple from the client side, but the server has a code path that is pretty significant.)

A connection pool is a commonly implemented approach. A connection pool manages a set of connections to the database; clients can "borrow" connections from the pool, so churning (lots of requests for connections) is handled by the pool, at the client side, and the database server sees a steady set of connections. so everyone is happy.